# Trouble in configuring mysql in ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, mysql

while trying to configure mysql in ubuntu i got the followig error
I tried reconfiguring but it wont work

PLease help me on this

[image]

Comment: Theres a window with this message...sorry i cant upload the screen shot

Comment: It looks like the error presented itself just before this screen.

Comment: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=fjdwyu&s=8#.VOzNv4WKg8o --->the screenshot

Comment: hmmm now I see what you meant. Weird; I'd expect an errormessage on the 3rd line.

Comment: how can i correct this...i alraedy tried reconfigurring a 100 times!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you installing mysql, because the screen says phpmyadmin. Which command do you use to install mysql?

```
sudo apt-get install mysql
```

you can have look at

```
/var/log/apt/term.log
```

there might be more information about the error